# Using the activeX Control "AcroPDF.dll" my application works fine, but crashes on startup if adobe acrobat is not installed

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, controls, activex

I have an application that adds text to PDF files, and I have a axAcroPDF1 preview panel that borrows acrobat to show the status of the PDF file, but it is not necessary for the function of the program, **so I'd like to have the program still start even when acrobat is not installed albeit more limited functionality**, and then the user just wont have a preview panel which is fine.  How can I do this?

The only thing I could think to try was adding a catch/exception when this.axAcroPDF1 is initializing when the program starts, which allows me to put a message popup that Adobe reader is required, but the program still crashes after that, so I would like to have the program start regardless, and just not call on that when adobe is not installed, or any other suggestions you guys have so that this application could still function somewhat with or without adobe.

I know how to check if adobe is installed, but I don't know how to apply the result to my program.

The catch exception on initializing gives the following error (I'm a noob so probably not giving good information here):

---

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: When your application crashes, is there an error message or an exception fired? Can you post the code around the use of axAcroPDF control?

Comment: I don't have c# installed on the machine without acrobat, but I just added the problem signature above, and I will see if I can find a more informative error output.

Comment: "Class not registered" == "Acrobat is not installed".

Comment: Hi Hans, agreed that is the problem, but I'm not sure how I can make the program still start instead of crashing, and just leave out the adobe functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I decided to use Inno Installer since I have some DLL files, and in the installer script, I do an adobe check, and if they dont have adobe or the right version I prompt the user to download reader.  Here is the basic code to check adobe:

```
    [Code]







 procedure ExitProcess(exitCode:integer);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall'; 

function GetAcrobatReaderVersion(): String;
var
  sVersion:  String;
begin
  sVersion := '';
  RegQueryStringValue( HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe',
     '', sVersion );
  GetVersionNumbersString( sVersion , sVersion );
  Result := sVersion;


end;

function GetAcrobatVersion(): String;
var
  sVersion2: String;
begin


    sVersion2 := '';
  RegQueryStringValue( HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Acrobat.exe',
     '', sVersion2 );
  GetVersionNumbersString( sVersion2 , sVersion2 );
  Result := sVersion2;
end;



function NextButtonClick(CurPage: Integer): Boolean;
begin



  // by default go to next page
  Result := true;

  if CurPage = wpWelcome then
  begin

    if Length( GetAcrobatReaderVersion + GetAcrobatVersion() ) = 0 then
    begin
      MsgBox( 'adobe not detected',  mbInformation, MB_OK );

      Result := false;
      ExitProcess(0);//adobe isn't installed, so exit installer
    end

    else
      //MsgBox( 'Acrobat reader installed is version ' + GetAcrobatReaderVersion() ,
      MsgBox( 'adobe detected',  mbInformation, MB_OK );


     end;
  end;
```